# Instalar NPM de un Proyecto

Tags: npm

tengo un problema al hacer `npm install` , el proyecto lo copio de un git pull en el que tengo que colaborar.
El problema es que para instalar las dependencias npm me da error, se me elimina el archivo node_modules. El error es como si no encontrase una ruta pero nose la verdad, he probado de todo.
Ayuda.

Le doy a `npm i` me sale esto:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1c\fe\7ff61a7651a66de5f624ba134147c63245c4fc8eec3cfae15b0267b9de237d85b96f2a72d44ca926c091baa1c5a920a7fc50ae03a1e586e2dcb427a4bafe
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1c\fe\7ff61a7651a66de5f624ba134147c63245c4fc8eec3cfae15b0267b9de237d85b96f2a72d44ca926c091baa1c5a920a7fc50ae03a1e586e2dcb427a4bafe'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-07T18_20_47_700Z-debug.log
```

Quiero hacer funcionar angular con `ng serve` y me sale esto:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'    
Require stack:
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\JRobe\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-3vNA5O\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Después de un rato como dije, se me elimina automáticamente el `node_modules`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y veas en la seccion "cómo preguntar". Primero que nada, no compartas imágenes para mostrar código, pega directamente los errores como texto, asi podemos ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: como te indicaron, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Las trazas de error deben ir _como texto, con formato_ para mejor legibilidad. Además, haz tu título más descriptivo: _problema al..._ es muy ambiguo. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, he actualizado la pregunta, he puesto los errores en codigo.

Comment: borra el `package-lock.json` y vuelve a intentarlo

Comment: Echa un ojo aquí, https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261#issuecomment-207623445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Muchas gracias a todos. El borrar el package-lock.json no me funcionó pero al entrar en el foro probé varias respuestas y la que me funcionó fue la de hacer `npm cache clean --force` y volver a `npm install`, ahi se me instalo todo correctamente. Gracias a los que respondisteis.

Comment: No pongas _solucionado_, en su lugar [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta (una vez transcurridas 48 hs luego de haberla escrito). Ten en cuenta que esto no es un foro, sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (tal como lo menciona el [tour]) :)